# Is this a Zelus luridus?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology

[image]

I found this little bug on my bed and I got curious to know what it was, I did some researches and then I noticed that it is very similar to *Zelus* Nymph but I can't be sure of it. Can you confirm it?

Here is a processed version of the image:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to say we still need a better picture; the focus (or rather lack thereof) makes any identification suspect (though looking at the front pair of legs as-is makes me suspect that any Assassin Bug identification is likely wrong).

Comment: Ok, thank you for the comment. If I can I'm taking a better picture.